# Clojure, implement range, why this solution doesn't work

Tags: clojure

I want to implement range function of clojure, why following code won't work ?

```
(fn [low high]
  (loop[low low
        ret []]
    (if(= low high)
    (list ret)
    (recur (inc low) (concat ret [low])))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

As the previous answers point out

- `(list ret)` is wrong. Replace it with `(seq ret)`. Note: To return exactly `()`, not `nil` for an empty sequence, use `(if (seq ret) (seq ret) ())`. Nil-punning probably makes this needless.
- `concat` is over the top. Use `conj` instead.

Also,

- Guard against runaway: `(my-range 10 0)` loops forever. Replace `=` with `>=`.

Making these changes,

```
(defn my-range [low high]
  (loop [low low, ret []]
    (if (>= low high)
      (if (seq ret) (seq ret) ())
      (recur (inc low) (conj ret low)))))
```

The remaining problem is that this is not lazy: it develops the whole vector before returning. For example,

```
(take 5 (my-range 42 (java.lang.Integer/MAX_VALUE)))
```

... seems to take forever, though you only want five elements. A simple lazy version is

```
(defn my-range [low high]
  (lazy-seq
    (if (>= low high) () (cons low (my-range (inc low) high)))))
```

Then

```
(take 5 (my-range 42 (java.lang.Integer/MAX_VALUE)))
;(42 43 44 45 46)
```

... is immediate.

[RedDeckWins's  `my-range2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334009/clojure-implement-range-why-this-solution-doesnt-work/#25334090) does just as well, and is neater.

EDIT: `range` returns a list, not a vector, changed return statement to `(if (seq ret) (seq ret) ())` in first implementation of `my-range`.

Comment: Possible typo: in your lazy version, shouldn't `range` be `my-range`?

Answer (score 4):

I've given two correct implementations below.  Your problem is you were wrapping your accumulator, which was already a list, in another sequence when you called (list ret).

```
(defn my-range [low high]
  (loop [low low
        ret []]
    (if (= low high)
      (seq ret)
      (recur (inc low) (conj ret low)))))

(defn my-range2 [low high]
  (take-while
    (partial > high)
    (iterate inc low)))
```

Edit: `range` doesn't include the upper limit parameter in its returned seq, changed `partial` in `my-range2` from `>=` to `>`.

Comment: conj and concat, list and sequence, difference ?

Comment: conj will add a single element to a sequence, think list.add in Java.  concat will concatenate sequences together, think list.addAll in Java.

Comment: seq is turning your vector into a sequence.  if you really wanted all the elements in ret in a list, you could have put (into '() ret) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, except for `(list ret)` part.

[`list` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/list) creates new list with given elements (in your example, with single `ret` element). If you want to convert your sequential, you should use [`seq` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/seq) instead.

I would also recommend you not to use [`concat` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/concat) here, because its lazy and may cause a `StackOwerflowError` producing long sequences.

The rest of your code is fine.

For working example see [RedDeckWins's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334009/clojure-implement-range-why-this-solution-doesnt-work/#25334090).